# standard deviation can not be calculated within dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to calculate some basic stats. Calculation of mean works but not of standard deviation.

```
  df%>% 
  group_by(date, name) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(rating = mean(rating, na.rm = T),
                   sd_rating = sd(rating, na.rm = T))
  #And this is working if I apply it on single vector?! 
  sd(df[df$date== "2016-07-22",]$rating)
```

Example data

```
df <- structure(list(bloc = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L), name = c("nn", "nn", "nn", "nn", "nn", "nn", "nn", "nn", 
"nn", "nn", "nn", "nn"), date = c("2016-07-22", "2016-07-22", 
"2016-07-22", "2016-07-22", "2016-07-22", "2016-07-22", "2016-07-29", 
"2016-07-29", "2016-07-29", "2016-07-29", "2016-07-29", "2016-07-29"
), rating = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(3L, 
86L, 133L, 206L, 280L, 305L, 339L, 422L, 469L, 542L, 616L, 641L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: In your summarize, you are replacing the `rating` column with `mean(rating)` so it just has one value and when you try to take the `sd()` of a single value, you get NA. This would work if you change the order `dplyr::summarise(sd_rating = sd(rating, na.rm = T), rating = mean(rating, na.rm = T))` or just call the mean column something other than `rating` so you don't overwrite the values in the column

Comment: Sorry about duplicate just have been looking for answer but did not find this one. I did not know that it works this way. Thanks.